# KVM not showing up in CentOS7

Tags: redhat, centos7, kvm

Trying to install KVM on CentOS7.

egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
produces the following result:

```
0
```

lsmod | grep kvm comes up empty

I used the following line when installing:

```
yum install qemu-kvm qemu-img virt-manager libvirt libvirt-python libvirt-client virt-install virt-viewer bridge-utils
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should work. I tried this and it worked for me. Unless your trying to install 64bit virtualization within a virtualized system. AKA nested virtualization. This does not work with virtualbox. VMWare supports this feature. You could also try Parallels. I think virtualbox supports 32bit nested virtualization but I would go with vmware for 64bit.

https://www.quora.com/VirtualBox-inside-VirtualBox-Is-that-possible
https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/4032

Comment: Thanks. I should have checked with the vm product.